# Can't get selected items

Tags: wpf, listbox, selecteditem

ListBoxItem property "**IsSelected**" binds to boolean property of my class.

```
public class TaxModel
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("isTaxInclusive")]
    public bool IsTaxInclusive { get; set; } // IsSelected
}
```

I set `CustomerTaxesListBox.ItemsSource = List<"TaxModel>` and some of them have `IsTaxInclusive = true.`

My question is:

When `CustomerTaxesListBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`, I can't get CustomerTaxesListBox.SelectedItems (It's empty). If ListBox is visible I can get SelectedItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an idea for workaround :** You can query from `List<TaxModel>` to get only `TaxModel's` having `IsTaxInclusive value = true`, because `IsSelected` is bound to `IsTaxInclusive`. And getting Items having property `IsSelected = true` is the same as getting `SelectedItems`.

Try it out, hope that works!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but solution is not appropriate. User may change selected items or may not. So I can't use original collection of TaxModel

Comment: Try to query from CustomerTaxesListBox.ItemsSource, can you?

Comment: If `ItemsSource` is also empty, then you need to make a property to store `List<TaxModel>`. Then bind ListBox's `ItemsSource` to that property. Hence you can query from that property to get collection of `TaxModel` with up-to-date `IsTaxInclusive` property value.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But not still clear, why SelectedItems collection is empty if ListBox is collapsed.

Comment: Knowing that behavior, I guess on `Collapsed` state application only preserve minimum properties value (`ItemsSource` property preserved and `SelectedItems` property doesn't). When the state is changed to `Visible`, the rest of properties filled based on preserved properties value. Hence, `SelectedItems` filled based on `IsTaxInclusive` property of `ItemsSource`.